# Detecting a tap on a DirectedLocationOverlay

Tags: android, osmdroid

It was very easy to attach a ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener to a ItemizedIconOverlay (it can be passed in the constructor). However, DirectedLocationOverlay has no such constructor.

I tried to do this:

```
    DirectedLocationOverlay LocalDeviceMarker = new DirectedLocationOverlay(this.getBaseContext())
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e,
                final MapView mapView)
        {
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    getTitle() + " lat: "
                            + mLocation.getLatitudeE6() + " long: "
                            + mLocation.getLongitudeE6(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true; // No one else should handle this event.
        }
    };
```

but that onSingleTapConfirmed seems to be triggered when I tap anywhere on the map (rather than just on the arrow as I would like). What is the correct way to do this? Also, the ItemizedIconOverlay allowed you to assign a "Title" to each item - is there a way to name these DirectedLocationOverlays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectedLocationOverlay is user contributed code and not really a part of the v1 Google API so it doesn't get a lot of attention. It is similar to the ItemizedOverlay and ItemizedIconOverlay but it doesn't have the hit test methods to detect tapping on the actual icon. It probably should have extended one of those classes when it was originally written. I would take a look at how we implement hit testing in the itemized overlays and implement the same thing in DirectedLocationOverlay. Or you will have to extend ItemizedIconOverlay and add rotation functionality to the draw methods.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had thought of those two options, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't just missing something easier before implementing those "lower level" changes.

Comment: I spent a while and got this working for a single directed item using the first method you suggested. That is, the DirectedLocationOverlay class needs to know it's position (setLocation), which doesn't really make sense, as the ITEM should know its position and the overlay should just display the collection of items. It seems like the right thing to do is modify OverlayItem so that each item has an mBearing (which would be set to 0 by default as to not change any current behavior). Then if the bearing of an item is non-zero, the ItemizedIconOverlay would rotate it. Thoughts?

Comment: This was actually quite easy, much cleaner than the other way, and removes the need for DirectedLocationOverlay altogether. I have posted an issue including the fix and a demo here: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=488&thanks=488&ts=1382113925